# Adding or removing items to Recyclerview gives error "The specified child already has a parent."

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Whenever I try to add or remove items from a recyclerview, the following error pops up and the app crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Code for Recyclerview

```
public class KeywordsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KeywordsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> keywords;
    private Context context;
    private int totalCount = 0;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Chip mChip;
        private View view;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            mChip = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chip);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_keyword, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder pvh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final String keyword = keywords.get(position);

        holder.mChip.setChipText(keyword);

        holder.mChip.setOnCloseClickListener(new OnCloseClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseClick(View v) {
                removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return keywords.size();
    }


    public KeywordsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.context = c;
    }

}
```

Code for adding item

```
public void addTo(String newDueItems) {
    this.keywords.add(0, newDueItems);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Code for removing item

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    this.keywords.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

No views are added or removed dynamically. All additions and removals are done by the above methods. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your question with code related to adapter? Also what is type of `keywords`?

Comment: @Sagar updated the original question

Comment: Is there a problem when you call addTo ()? More information is needed.

Comment: can you add the code for `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I think you are adding views dynamically and this problem is related to dynamically added views. Post your related code for dynamic views

Comment: the problem is when I call addTo and removeItem. @AbuYousuf No views are added dynamically. See onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Where are you calling `addTo` method ?